# Switch tabs in mat-tab-group in sync with another identical component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-tab-group in a component called "person". In a parent component called "persons", I have two identical person components, and each of them has 3 tabs in its mat-tab-group. I want the components to be synchronized with their selected tab. For example, when I switch for tab 1 to tab 2 in one person, the second person should also do that.

I tried using @Input and @Output to communicate between the parent component and its children, but that didn't work. I also tried using a service to hold the currently selected tab, but I'm missing something because the components still do not sync.

That's the parent component:

```
<app-person-source [person]="persons[0]"></app-person-source>
<app-person-source [person]="persons[1]"></app-person-source>
```

And that's the child component:

```
<mat-tab-group class="demo-tab-group">
    <mat-tab>
      <person-details-tab></person-details-tab>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab>
      <person-identifiers-tab></person-identifiers-tab>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab>
      <person-merged-persons-tab></person-merged-persons-tab>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work using `ngrx store`, with 3 actions and effects. Code is pretty similar to:

https://www.logisticinfotech.com/blog/easiest-demo-to-learn-ngrx-in-angular-6/

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, you can create a shared service to sync data between components. Service code should be as follows:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {
    private tabIndexChanged$: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

    get tabIndexChanged(): Observable<number> {
        return this.tabIndexChanged$.asObservable();
    }

    tabChanged(tabIndex: number): void {
        this.tabIndexChanged$.next(tabIndex);
    }
}
```

After injecting this service in your child components, you need to subscribe to the service in the children:

```
this.sharedService.tabIndexChanged.subscribe(tabChanged => {
    // logic after tab changed should be here
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I injected and subscribed to the service in the child component, but the functionality of the tabs is still only in the child component, so I can't control both children from the parent component that contains them.

Comment: As far as I understand, you don't need to control children from the parent, you can do this from the service. After you change tab in one child, you can call tabChanged(tabIndex) method in the child, then you can get tabIndex in another child by subscribing to the subject as shown on the answer post. Is that clear for you? Let me know if that works for your case.